# VB Object var is nothing in recursion

Tags: vba, recursion

I am writing script in some Visual Basic dialect. I want to make recursion function but inside I have message that Object var is nothing. When I try to get object in main function everything works but after entering Sub object is nothing

```
Private Sub Search(ByRef draw As DrawingElements)
    For index0 = 0 To draw.Count
        Dim subDrawing As DrawingElement
        Set subDrawing = draw(index0)
        If subDrawing.DrawingElements.Count<>0 Then - Here I cannot Access Count because .DrawingElements Are nothing
            Search(subDrawing.DrawingElements)
        End If
        MsgBox(subDrawing.Type & " " & CStr(subDrawing.X) & " "& CStr(subDrawing.Y))
    Next
End Sub
Sub Main
    Dim App As Application
    Set App = New Application
    App.Show True
    With App.Packages(0).ActiveSheet
        Dim draw As DrawingElements
        Set draw = .DrawingElements
        Dim subDrawing As DrawingElement
        Set subDrawing =draw(0)
        MsgBox(CStr(subDrawing.DrawingElements.Count)) - Here I can acces Count and DrawingElements

        Search(.DrawingElements)
    End With
End Sub
```

I am not fluent in Visual basic so I don't know what to do. I tried ByRef and ByVal and I have the same result.

Comment: That's not VBScript. Use the correct tags for the application **and** its API language.

Comment: VBA <> VB <> VBS - Is this Visual Basic? Or Visual Basic for Application?

Answer (score 0):

I googled for "DrawingElements" but got no hits. With `Set App = New Application` you create one or another sort of application that apparently has a Package and an ActiveSheet.

But OK. Apparently that sheet has a *collection* of DrawingElements and each element (DrawingElement) can consist of other collections of DrawingElements. But somewhere this has to stop, and then that collection will be empty, i.e. its value is `Nothing`. Try:

```
If (subDrawing.DrawingElements Is Nothing) Then   ' end of recursion
```

Comment: In Search Sub DrawingElements are nothing on first recursion. Count property is accesible and tells me that there are 50 DrawingElements but when I want to extract one I have error. In main Sub everything works.

Comment: No you are not, in the sub you are accessing one _child_ at-a-time of the parent and you immediately access its `DrawingElements` COLLECTION there. That collection is apparently .empty. To be precise, in the first call to the sub you access there `App.Packages(0).ActiveSheet.DrawingElements(index0).DrawingElements.Count`

Comment: Sorry, When expanding the expressions I see they are the same in main's MsgBox and in the sub, so Count should be accessible. Maybe VB is confused. Try declaring everything as `Object` and removing the `With`. Further I see often the loops using a `For each` to iterate over collections.

Answer (score -1):

In VBA object collections are usually 1-based, not 0-based:

```
For index0 = 1 To draw.Count
```

as well as

```
With App.Packages(1).ActiveSheet
```

and

```
Set subDrawing =draw(1)
```

Comment: VBA arrays are 0 based unless `Option Base 1` is declared at module level.

Comment: That is wrong. See Option Base statement: "_Used at module level to declare the default lower bound for array subscripts. Because the default base is 0, the Option Base statement is never required_".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I don't understand what you are contesting - I'm explaining why the statement `In VBA arrays and collections are 1-based, not 0-based:` is incorrect...

Comment: Sorry @Macro-man, I am not contesting your comment (which you wrote while I wrote mine), but the statement of this incorrect answer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie aaah, okay that makes more sense! crossed wires :)

Comment: @Macro-man Guys? I should have left out the "array" part as that is incorrect. But most all of the object collections in VBA, be it Excel Sheets, Workbooks, Shapes etc. Word Tables, Styles, Shapes etc. are ALL 1-based. Now loolk back up the the OPs code and say it ain't so.

Comment: @LocEngineer no one is contesting the `Collections` bit, but stating that arrays are 0-based is wrong - hence the downvote. If you want to edit your answer I'll happily retract that vote. On a side note, we're still not sure if the OP is even using VBA - I suspect it is still VB.

Comment: @Macro-man fair enough, edited. Also the OP does not state what Application and version we are talking about - a fairly important bit of info. Using `DrawingElements` and `Application` instead of `xyzApp.DrawingElements` is a hint for either VBA or simply wrong programming.

Comment: This is BluePrint from Downstream

Comment: I see! So this is a so-called Visual Basic "script" as described in the FAQ? Does changing the starting index from 0 to 1 have an effect? P.S: if you start at 0, the upper limit for the loop is .Count - 1 anyway. That said, your problem starts earlier.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Zero base index works in main. I created if object is nothing show message box and in Sub Search I just have 50 times message boxes on first recursion. I am passing DrawingElements to Sub,  I can access Count Property (draw.Count - value = 50) but when I want to extract one of drawingElements draw(15) - all of 50 are empty.